# Angular 4 Parent-Child consistent data transfer

Tags: angular, function, typescript, typescript2.0

I'm having a problem with this small task while learning Angular 4.
I've tried reading about data transfer between components and I've tried reading about 2 way binding - none seem to work.

I'll post my Parent and Child component's .ts and .html files

Parent .ts file :

```
 import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cca-bank',
  templateUrl: './cca-bank.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cca-bank.component.css']
})
export class CcaBankComponent implements OnInit {

  bank:string = 'asd';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Parent .html file:

```
<div>
  <h3>Enter your Bank's name to see it's aviable branches</h3>
  <input [(ngModel)]="bank" placeholder="Enter your bank's name"/>
</div>
<app-cca-bank-branches [check]="bank"></app-cca-bank-branches>
```

Child .ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input,Output,EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cca-bank-branches',
  templateUrl: './cca-bank-branches.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cca-bank-branches.component.css']
})
export class CcaBankBranchesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  @Input() check:string;

  branch:string;

  checkBranch(check){
    if(this.check == "poalim"){
     this.branch = 'aviable branches are 1 2 3';
     return this.branch
    }else{
      this.branch = 'error';
      return this.branch
    }
  };
  ngOnInit() {
    this.branch = this.checkBranch(this.check);
  }
}
```

Child .html file:

```
<div>
  List of aviable Branches :
  {{branch}}<br>
  {{check}}
</div>
```

What I am aiming for is that when ever the user writes into the parent input - the child gets that input and runs it in the "checkBranch()" function and checks its value : unless the user writes "poalim" it should always return and error.

What happens is that the first value that the "bank" variable, in the parent's .ts file, is the value that the child gets. And no matter how many times I change it - it won't change dynamically - 
what happens is that unless the "bank" variable is set to "poalim" to begin with - no matter how many times I change the input - it won't change.
I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that I run the function in the NgOnInit part of the class - but I can't seem to find a way to run it differently...

I must have the logic happening in the .ts file (Done it through the HTML file and it did work - now I need the ts file to preform the functionality of my code)

Thanks in advance ! really, I've been trying for 5 hours now.

Comment: Have you looked into watching changes on your `check` input via the `OnChanges` life cycle hook?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of detecting and acting when an input changes in the child component in angular, `ngOnChanges()` or the `input property setter`

1. The ngOnChanges() lifecycle:

@Input() check: string;

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {

    this.checkBranch(changes.check.currentValue);
    // You can check.previousValue and check.firstChange for comparing the old and new value
}
```

2. The input property setter as follows

private _check: string;

```
@Input() set check(value: string) {
   this._check= value;
   this.checkBranch(this._check);

}

get check(): string {
    return this._check;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! the first comment actually did the job! but you expended a bit on it and I  appreciate it! thanks a bunch! i'll give those a try :)

Comment: No problem R' Goren. Remember to select a correct answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should instead do your processing of the `check` input in the `OnChanges` life cycle hook instead of the `OnInit` one.

```
import { ... OnChanges, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';

@Component(...)
export class CcaBankBranchesComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  ...
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if (changes['check']) {
      this.branch = this.checkBranch(this.check);
    }
  }
}
```